# ExtJs4 MVC, data.store for combo box

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs4

I want to define the data.store that store companyList, because I want to reuse this store later.

```
tbar: Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar', {
    items: [
        {
        xtype : 'combo',
        name : 'companyCode',
        editable : false,
        valueField : 'companyCode',
        displayField : 'companyName',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                fields: ['companyCode', 'companyName'],
                proxy: {
                type: 'ajax', 
                url: '/Reports/GetCompanyList/',
                reader: 'json',
                actionMethods: {
                    read: 'POST'
                }
                },
                autoLoad:true  
            })
```

The above code is work, and I want to put the store into my store folder under the app folder.

store/CompanyList_store.js

```
Ext.define('App.store.CompanyList_store', {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    fields: ['companyCode', 'companyName'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/Reports/GetCompanyList/',
        reader: 'json',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'POST'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true  
});
```

and I add this store in controller.

```
Ext.define("App.controller.InventoryReport", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    stores: ['Inventory_store', 'CompanyList_store'],
    .
    .
```

and add this store to combo box store,

```
tbar: Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar', {
    items: [
        {
        xtype : 'combo',
        name : 'companyCode',
        editable : false,
        valueField : 'companyCode',
        displayField : 'companyName',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        store: 'CompanyList_store' //it does not work.
```

What I am doing wrong? If anybody knows, please advice me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotta set the storeId property on the store, to the value that you call from the combo

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore-cfg-storeId

In real life though, I would recommend using Deft's dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to include all stores in your application file.

It should be something like this:

```
Ext.application({
  appFolder: ...
  controllers: [your controllers here],
  stores: [your stores here]
});
```

And if you place your store in different folder (to share them between ext apps) be sure you included the following:
`Ext.Loader.setPath([namespace], [path to the folder with stores]`)